# How to send data to next thread, if the previous threads return different types?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This problem is being solved only on **C++**. I have *thread chain* that is defined on a go. So, let us say that **a thread with number 0** is waiting results that are returned by **threads 1, 2 and 3**.

```
    void thread0()
{
   vector<int> numbers_of_children_lists;
   vector<???> results_of_previos_calc;   

   for(auto i : numbers_of_children_lists)
   {

     results_of_previos_calc.push_back(GetResult(List[i]));
   }

   /*some operation on this given parameters*/
   /*what a type*/ result = ...;
   struct Node *a;
   a->result = result;
   List[some_num].push(a); /*and so on*/

}
```

`List[i]` contains nodes that are pushed by previous threads when they ended their work up

```
struct Node
{
   /*what a type?*/ result;
}
```

So I want that thread0 can take any parameters in own container with universal type. To be precise, thread1 returns integer type, thread2 returns string type and thread3 returns boolean.
0-thread containers of parameters should be able to operate with parameters of any type. Is it possible?

P.S. I cannot know what a type returns a thread while programs is compiled, because I will assign some structure objects to this functions and I will call overrided operators that may return anything

Comment: _"I cannot know what a type returns a thread while programs is compiled"_ vs _"To be precise, thread1 returns integer type, thread2 returns string type and thread3 returns boolean"_ Which one is true? Do you know what thy return or not?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is some sort of discriminated union of types. Like a variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> P.S. I cannot know what a type returns a thread while programs is compiled, because I will assign some structure objects to this functions and I will call overrided operators that may return anything

If you truely don't know what type that is then there is nothing you can do beyond storing pointer to it in `void*`. But then you can't even delete it properly.

In C++ there a few methods one can to deal with somewhat unknown types.

1) If it can be of, say, three types `int`, `double`, or `std::string` then you use `std::variant` which will identify which type it is. Or make a struct that has these types as members and an enum to identify which type it is.

2) Make a shared abstract interface for all return types and return them via pointers. This is the object oriented style.

Unlike Python - in C++ you cannot identify what type is returned if you only know its address or something - if variable is returned but you have no access to its definition, then you'll find it difficult to compile the code at all and you need access to its class definition to use it (in any meaningful way beyond passing pointers/references). This is because in Python extra information is stored that allows code to identify the types - it is not the case in C++ where you have to mamage the identification process yourself when needed.

Comment: what about `std::any`. Does it help me out? and can you give me an example of "shared abstract interface" please?

Comment: @AyratArifullin `std::any` can store any type and has type safe casting procedures - so it can be helpful. There is also typeid access... not sure how to properly use in C++. About "abstract interface " just google "C++ interface" for guides on this matter. There is enough material online.